# Htaccess ModRewrite: remove www and change a directory name

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have Urls like the one below in my blog.

`http://www.domain.com/live/comments/the_winter_is_set_to_end_the_same_way_it_began_on_a_very_mild_note/`

There is two things I really want to change.
-the www has got to go
-the word comments should be set to 'post' (not all Urls contain the word comments)

Resulting in an Url like
`http://sion.com/live/post/the_winter_is_set_to_end_the_same_way_it_began_on_a_very_mild_note/`

The thing is I can't change the Urls the blog provides. i just want to change them dynamically in htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code you will need:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(live)/comments/(.*)$ http://sion.com/$1/post/$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```